# Adding object to existing NSMutableArray causes exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, exception, nsmutablearray

I want to add an object to an existing `NSMutableArray` which already has  data in it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSDictionary *json = [Server getMsgRecordwithfid:self.fid];
    self.msgRecords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.msgRecords = [json objectForKey:@"msg_record"];
}
- (IBAction)sendBtn:(id)sender {
    NSDictionary *json = [Server insertNewMsg:data];
    [self.msgRecords addObject:json];
}
```

When I run the above code, the program crashes at `[self.msgRecords addObject:json];`. And then it gives the below error message.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's wrong of my code?

Your code is writing over the `NSMutableArray`, replacing a mutable collection with an immutable one that you retrieve from json.

To fix this, call `mutableCopy` on the array that you retrieve:

```
// The first line is no longer necessary
//self.msgRecords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.msgRecords = [[json objectForKey:@"msg_record"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: It's working now. Thank for your help and explanation! @dasblinkenlight